# android studio plugin with id: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I am using gradle and I am trying to add kotlin to my project. But when I am trying to add 'kotlin-android-extensions' plugin for gradle it fails to find it.

Answer (score 4):

To use the plugin, you have to add it in your root level file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Comment: @ZiadSaad is it a question?  If it is not working, post your build.gradle and the details of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following to your gradle.build file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

after that you have to make some changes in your dependencies classpath like this.

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}
```

and in dependencies compile make sure to add jre7 such that.

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
```

After doing all that rebuild the gradle and you are all done. This worked for me because i was facing the same problem you are now, and after this it's all done. Hope it works for you tooo....

Answer (score 0):

classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:+"
try this

Comment: Please try to add an explanation on how your method tends to solve the query.